# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, apache, curl, xampp

I'm new to the php.

When I'm trying to connect to crea(Canada realestate)  database I encountered a error

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\cr\PHRets_CREA.php on line 1465

again I executed the code then it is showing

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\cr\PHRets_CREA.php on line 1408

Then I changed the following line in php.ini and restarted my server

```
max_execution_time=300
```

This time it again sown different line number

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\cr\PHRets_CREA.php on line 1489

How to overcome this problem?

Here the complete code is  http://crea.ca/data-distribution-facility-documentation

Comment: You must probably restart your server

Comment: when you change php.ini settings a restart is required, some ini settings can be set per file, in which case no restart is required. so you can add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` to the file instead of edding php.ini

Comment: @Dagon I restarted my server but still it showing error

Comment: @Dagon Then it showing third time as Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Comment: use set_time_limit(0) at the top of script

Comment: more time or tweak the script, i dont know how much it requires

Comment: unlimited is a little dangerous

Comment: How much time should it take the script to execute? 5 minutes is pretty substantial.

Comment: i have scripts that run for hours, but you want to know what your doing in such  case :-)

Comment: @VipinSoni instead of giving unlimited time, might be useful to know _why_ it takes that long and correct that. When you have fever, you don't suggest "buy a termometer with a larger scale"

Comment: If you are using sample code provided by the "http://crea.ca/data-distribution-facility-documentation". Can u show your download.php /* RETS Variables */ values.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your script is taking too much time to execute and it is being timedout.

Edit your php.ini and change the value of max_execution_time to 1000 and restart your web server.

You can also try to increase your memory_limit.