# Read excel in php

Tags: php, excel

I have PHP 5.3.29 installed and trying to read an excel file with `php-excel-reader-2.21`, but it gives error as below

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in php-excel-reader-2.21\excel_reader2.php on line 143
```

Also tried to use `phpExcelReader`, it gives error as below.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\phpExcelReader\Spreadsheet\Excel\Reader\oleread.php on line 96
```

Working on maximum time limit may not be helpful here as I have only 2 rows to read in excel file and for that the value "300" I have set is already high. anyone has idea on why the libraries failing to read excel? or any alternative suggestions?

Comment: Anything not clear about the error message?

Comment: Also possible dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176773/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709161/maximum-execution-time-of-300-seconds-exceeded-in-pcntl-fork, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5164930/508666, http://stackoverflow.com/q/22421876/508666, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23556519/508666

Comment: Issue is not about working on maximum execution time, because I have only 2 rows in the excel I am using to read, so the value I have set is already high. I want to understand why the specified libraries are failing to read excel or suggestions on any other library would be helpful.

Comment: If that is the case you should have putted that in your question instead of letting people mind read what it is you want to ask? Also software suggestions are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

In your `php.ini` file there is a directive `max_execution_time`, change it to what you want.

OR

in your PHP script, write following line:

```
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);
```